# Domain restrictions for swfloader

Tags: c#, html, flash, actionscript

I have a swf movie player located in http://www.a.com/a.swf. Normally this a.swf is used by a html page, the swf file is embedded in a http://www.a.com/a.html. The website is not built by me but I know there is a restriction that only the html in http://www.a.com can play the video . Now what I want to do is embed the a.swf into a c# project using swfloader, I will set the source property of swfloader to http://www.a.com/a.swf. My question is will the c# project be able to play to video file the same as in the html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't matter what serverside language you are using as long it prints out html. Only the html and actionscript settings matter. If you allow networking, by using this `<param value="all" name="allownetworking"/>` it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. But the restrictions are put on the content side, something like when the swf file is trying to get the content file using http protocol, the content server will verify the http request is actually coming from domain http://www.a.com. So I wonder once the c# project is going to play the content, what will be inside the http header's domain section, will the domain section be http://www.a.com?

Comment: it depends how the actionscript programmer wrote the URLRequest. it could be: 'http://www.a.com/my/api' or it could be: '/my/api' that would force you to recreate the same api on the server your are hosting this swf. maybe this doesnt help you much, but i cant give you a better answer, because i dont understand what "http header's domain section" is.